# How to allow anonymous access to mvc pages in aspx project - Error message 401.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I allow anonymous for this one MVC page in a ASPX project?

In a traditional ASP.NET project (aspx pages), there is some MVC pages that co-exist and work within the framework. I recently added a MVC controller and forgotpassword.cshtml page that works only when I'm logged in. The controller has the allow anonymous attribute but this is not honored in this project since only part of a MVC framework exists in the project. I set "Context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect" in application begin request and this helps with the re-direct back to login but I'm getting an unauthorized error.

Error:

```
Access is denied.
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3535.0
```

AccountController.cs

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : SessionReadController
{
    public AccountController(IUserSecurityService userSecurityService, ILogger logger)
        : base()
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

Global.asax.cs

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Request.Path.Contains("forgotpassword"))
    {
        Context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the attribute [Authorize] in the class level to make [AllowAnonymous] attribute works and put [AuthorizedAction] attribute in the desired function that you want authenticated.

```
public class AccountController : SessionReadController
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult AuthorizedPage()
    {
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
      public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
      {
         return View();
      }
}
```

Comment: The type or namespace AuthorizedActionAttribute could not be found.

Comment: try using just [Authorized]

Comment: misspelled - [Authorize] 
Refer to ...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api